# Redirect after Basic Http Auth Express.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, redirect, express, http-auth

I want to make a private access to an application using express.js like .htaccess and .htpasswd do in my php project.

I'm using [http-auth](https://github.com/gevorg/http-auth)

Here is my code :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  basic.apply(req, res, function(username) {
    res.redirect(routes.index);
  });
});
```

The problem is I get an error :

> 500 TypeError: Object function (req, res){ res.render('index', { title: 'Express' }); } has no method 'indexOf'

Without authentication,

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

works without any troubles.

I think about a middleware to read my index and then use res.send()... May it works?
or what did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

I think the argument to `res.redirect` needs to be a URL string, right ? You seem to be passing in a request handler (`function (req, res) {...}`).

Comment: well, in that way, using res.redirect is not good. Because I need url rewriting.
http:// url.com / -> call routes/index.js

Comment: Yeah. You could probably just remove the call to `res.redirect` entirely and just invoke your `routes.index` handler function directly inside the `basic.apply` callback ?

Comment: I already tried it, but maybe I was wrong.
  basic.apply(req, res, function(username) { //... }, routes.index);
This doesn't return an error but it doesn't call index neither

Comment: That's right, you need to actually call the handler yourself: `routes.index(req, res)`.

Comment: Isn't question about `http-auth` usage, if so this don't answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I think usage [pattern now is different](http://http-auth.info)

```
// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// Application setup.
var app = express();

// Setup route.
app.get('/', auth.connect(basic), routes.index);
```